# Can anyone explain to me what this shifting means under this circumstance: uint16_t register0 = (instruction >> 9) & 0x7

Tags: c, virtual-machine, bit-manipulation

I'm trying to write a VM (LC-3), and on this ADD instruction I encountered this statement. Basically the "register0" is the DR register, but I don't really understand what is actually shifting and why 9. Also the AND operator with the 0x7 value.

```
|15|14|13|12|11|10|9|8|7|6|5|4|3|2|1|0|
|    0001   |  DR   | SR1 |0| 00| SR2 |
```

Could anyone please explain it to me in detail?

```
ADD {
    /* destination register (DR) */
    uint16_t r0 = (instr >> 9) & 0x7;
    /* first operand (SR1) */
    uint16_t r1 = (instr >> 6) & 0x7;
    /* whether we are in immediate mode */
    uint16_t imm_flag = (instr >> 5) & 0x1;
    if (imm_flag) {
        uint16_t imm5 = sign_extend(instr & 0x1F, 5);
        reg[r0] = reg[r1] + imm5;
    } else {
        uint16_t r2 = instr & 0x7;
        reg[r0] = reg[r1] + reg[r2];
    }
    update_flags(r0);
}
```

Comment: Aligned the bit descriptions for you. Unsure what `ADD` means,

Comment: The DR is 3 bits. The code obtains its value by shifting the word to the right with `instr >> 9`, and masking off these 3 bits with `& 0x7`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it's doing is isolating the 3 bits that represent the `DR` register so they become a standalone number.

Let's say the entire sequence looks like this:

```
1110101101101011
    ^^^
     DR
```

Shifting 9 bits right gives this:

```
1110101
```

and `& 0x7` (bitwise AND) isolates the 3 lowest bits:

```
101
```

Similar operations are performed to isolate the values of `SR1` and the immediate mode flag. Depending on that flag, `SR2` may also be required, but as it's already in the lowest 3 bits, no shifting is needed.

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane - I updated to reflect that.